# In React JS Pass an Input value onSubmit from a child to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent

In my application, I have a child component: Post, which has an input text box to submit some data.

My Parent component Posts should take this input value data from the child and post it to the google Firebase database upon submitting it via the function addAnswerHandler().

How can I pass the value in the input with inputname=Answer from the child component to the parent function postAnswerHandler().

```
React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Link, Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Answered from '../../containers/Blog/answered/answered-posts';
import './Post.css';

import RothIRA_1 from '../../containers/Types/RothIRA_1';



function post (props) { 
  
return (
    <article key={props.id} className="Post" onClick={props.clicked}>
       <h1>{props.key_1}</h1>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
         <p className="Body-Content">{props.body}</p>
           <div className="Info">

             <div className="Answer-Section">
   
              <input type="text" className="Question-Answer" name="Answer" value={'test'} 
              placeholder="Your Answer..." ></input>
       
        <li className="Answer-Button"><input type="submit" value="Answer" id="submitButton" /></li>
    </div>
        <ul>
       
            <li className="Type-Link"><NavLink to={{
                pathname: '/'+ props.type,
                hash: '#submit',
                search: '?quick-submit=true'
                }}>{props.type}</NavLink></li>
            
                        
        </ul>
        
    </div>
        
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/RothIRA" component={RothIRA_1} />
            <Route path="/answered" component={Answered} />
             {/* <Route path={'/' + props.type} component={RothIRA_1} /> */}
             {/* <Route path= {'/'+ props.type} component={RothIRA} /> */}
             


        </Switch>
    </article>
    
 );
}
export default post;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axios';
import { Link, Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Post from '../../../components/Post/Post';
import './Posts.css';
import FullPost from '../FullPost/FullPost';
import Answered from '../answered/answered-posts';
import Unanswered from '../../Unanswered/Unanswered-Posts';
import Myquestions from '../My-Questions/Myquestions';
import RothIRA_1 from '../../Types/RothIRA_1'

class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        
        axios.get( 'https://blog-6d4da-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json' )
            .then( response => {
                let posts = Object.values(response.data);
                let keys = Object.keys(response.data);
              
                const updatedPosts = keys.map( key => {    
                    return {
                        key, ...response.data[key],
                        
                    }
                } );
                   
                    this.setState( { posts: updatedPosts } );

               
             
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
                
            } );
    }

    postAnswerHandler = ( id, question_answer ) => {
       
        const data = {
            answer: question_answer

        };
         const data_1 = JSON.stringify(data);
         axios.put('/posts/'+id+'.json', data);

    }

    

   

    render () {
        let posts = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Something went wrong!</p>;
        if ( !this.state.error ) {
            posts = this.state.posts.map( (post) => {
                return (
                    
                    <Post
                        key={post.key}
                        id={post.key}
                        title={post.title}
                        type={post.type}
                        body={post.body}
                        answer={post.answer}
                        clicked={() => this.postAnswerHandler(post.key, post.answer)}
                         />
                        
                    
                );
            } );
        }

        return (
            <div className="Posts-Page">
            
                <section className="Posts">
                    {posts}
                </section>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: use onChange on the input as pass the postAnswerHandler with the id and extraData

Comment: Passing data between child and parent is usually done with value and callback props passed from the parent to the child. Here is a quick example of using a callback: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-phxmkd

Comment: pass callback function parent to child component and pass updated state value pass child to parent function.

Comment: Thanks super helpful! I will try these solutions out I think I will be able to get it.

Comment: @JacobSmit is there a way to pass the id of the child back to the parent along with the value from the input. Basically id is sent as props and I want to tell object to push the value to in a database and I need the id to do so.

Comment: You are fully in control of the onSubmit function and it's parameters, make the onSubmit function use `(id, value) => { /*do some stuff*/ }` and then in the child component you should be able to change the onClick of the submit button to `() => onSubmit(id, value)`.

Comment: @JacobSmit Awesome thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JacobSmit I have my parent as onChange={(value, id) => this.postAnswerHandler(value,id)} and my child as onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value)}. Why is is passing id as undefined. Id is being passed as props as the objects key from database.

Comment: `props.onChange(event.target.value)` is only passing a single param, you have to also pass the id back. i.e. `props.onChange(event.target.value, props.id)`

Comment: @JacobSmit I got this to work thanks for the help was so useful!